# Set Max value on number form in Repeater Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I made an Repeater for my form and I want set `max=""` to a number field by selecting in a droplist with `data-max="futureMaxValueHere"`.

This is the first row:

```
<div id="newlink" class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="row">
        <div id='produitdiv' class="form-group col-md-8">
            <select class="form-control" name="produit[]" id="produit" onchange="getMax(this.parentNode.parentNode.id)">
                <option value="choix">Choisir un produit</option>
                <?php for($i = 0; $i < count($arrayInventaire); $i++){
                    echo '<option value="'.$arrayInventaire[$i]['nom_du_materiel'].'" data-max="'.$arrayInventaire[$i]['quantite_autorisee_par_commande'].'">'.$arrayInventaire[$i]['nom_du_materiel'].'</option>';

                    $arrayProduits[$i]['nom'] = $arrayInventaire[$i]['nom_du_materiel'];
                    $arrayProduits[$i]['max'] = $arrayInventaire[$i]['quantite_autorisee_par_commande'];
                }?>
            </select>
        </div> 
        <div id='nombrediv' class="form-group col-md-3 col-xs-10">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="nombre[]" id="nombre" max="" min="0">
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="javascript:new_link()"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the repeater:

```
<div id="newlinktpl" style="display:none">
<div class="row">
    <div id='produitdiv' class="form-group col-md-8">
        <select class="form-control" name="produit[]" id="produit" onchange="getMax(this.parentNode.parentNode.id)">
            <option value="choix">Choisir un produit</option>
            <?php for($i = 0; $i < count($arrayInventaire); $i++){
                echo '<option value="'.$arrayInventaire[$i]['nom_du_materiel'].'" data-max="'.$arrayInventaire[$i]['quantite_autorisee_par_commande'].'">'.$arrayInventaire[$i]['nom_du_materiel'].'</option>';
            }?>
        </select>
    </div> 
    <div id='nombrediv' class="form-group col-md-3 col-xs-10">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="nombre[]" id="nombre" max="" min="0">
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:new_link()"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href="javascript:" onClick='delIt(this.parentNode.parentNode.id)'><i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" style="color:red;"></i></a>
</div>
```

function for repeater add an delete (JS):

```
var ct = 1;
function new_link()
{
    ct++;
    var div1 = document.createElement('div');
    div1.id = ct;
    div1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('newlinktpl').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('newlink').appendChild(div1);
}
// function to delete the newly added set of elements
function delIt(eleId)
{
    d = document;
    var ele = d.getElementById(eleId);
    var parentEle = d.getElementById('newlink');
    parentEle.removeChild(ele);
}
```

This is the function (JS):

```
function getMax(element){
    doc = document;
    var ele = doc.getElementById(element);
    var select = doc.getElementById('produit');
    var number = doc.getElementById('nombre');
    jQuery(number).prop('max',jQuery(select).find(':selected').data("max"));
    console.log("max: " + jQuery(select).find(':selected').data("max"));

}
```

The function works with the first row. Subsequent rows return the `data-max` of the select's first row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, IDs are unique (meaning they should appear once in the DOM). Because you will be re-using the repeater i.e. template, ensure that you don't use any IDs in them. Change `produitdiv`, `nombrediv`, and `nombre` to classes.

Second, you are using jQuery: leverage it. Stop using ugly `document.getElementByWhatever` and `on*` attributes. Instead, use [$(selector)](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) syntax and [event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Now, because you are dynamically creating elements, you'll need to create delegated event handlers. For more information, read [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/#event-propagation).

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  // attach an onchange event handler to all dropdowns
  $(document).on('change', 'select[name="produit[]"]', function() {
    // create jQuery object out of current element
    var select = $(this);
    // get selected max value
    var maxVal = select.find(':selected').data('max');
    // get related nombre[] field
    // both produit[] and nombre[] field share the same containing .row div
    var row = select.closest('.row');
    // then search for nombre[] within the container
    var input = row.find('input[name="nombre[]"]');
    // set nombre[]'s max value
    input.attr('max', maxVal);
  });

  // attach onclick event handler to all New links
  $(document).on('click', '.new', function(e) {
    // this is a link, so prevent the link from doing anything
    e.preventDefault();
    // add new row after current row
    $(this).closest('.row').after($('#template').html());
  });

  // attach onclick event handler to all Delete links
  $(document).on('click', '.delete', function(e) {
    // this is a link, so prevent the link from doing anything
    e.preventDefault();
    // delete current row
    $(this).closest('.row').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <!-- change ID to class -->
  <div class="form-group col-md-8 produitdiv">
    <select class="form-control" name="produit[]">
         <option value="choix">Choisir un produit</option>
   <!-- let's just suppose data-max = N in Produit #N -->
         <option data-max="1">Produit #1</option>
   <option data-max="2">Produit #2</option>
   <option data-max="3">Produit #3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <!-- change ID to class -->
  <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-xs-10 nombrediv">
    <input type="number" class="form-control nombre" name="nombre[]" max="0" min="0">
  </div>
  <div>
    <!-- add class -->
    <a href="#" class="new">New</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="template" style="display:none">
  <!-- same thing -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-8 produitdiv">
      <select class="form-control" name="produit[]">
   <option value="choix">Choisir un produit</option>
   <option data-max="1">Produit #1</option>
   <option data-max="2">Produit #2</option>
   <option data-max="3">Produit #3</option>
   </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-xs-10 nombrediv">
      <input type="number" class="form-control nombre" name="nombre[]" max="0" min="0">
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="new">New</a>
      <!-- add class -->
      <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps in your repeater is missing `</div>` 
and select box and a tag call to delIt function is not in one container so 
I see you using jQuery, so i have a solution for this

html code, you use only this

```
<div id="newlink" class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div id='produitdiv' class="form-group col-md-8">
        <select class="form-control" name="produit[]" onchange="getMax(this)">
            <option value="choix">Choisir un produit</option>
            <?php for($i = 0; $i < count($arrayInventaire); $i++){
                echo '<option value="'.$arrayInventaire[$i]['nom_du_materiel'].'" data-max="'.$arrayInventaire[$i]['quantite_autorisee_par_commande'].'">'.$arrayInventaire[$i]['nom_du_materiel'].'</option>';

                $arrayProduits[$i]['nom'] = $arrayInventaire[$i]['nom_du_materiel'];
                $arrayProduits[$i]['max'] = $arrayInventaire[$i]['quantite_autorisee_par_commande'];
            }?>
        </select>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-xs-10">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="nombre[]"  max="" min="0">
    </div>
    <div class="control-wrap">
        <a href="javascript:new_link()"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I removed all id attribute because id is unique, and add class control-wrap to a div.
And here is javascript code

```
var repeater = jQuery(jQuery('#newlink').html());
 repeater.find('.control-wrap').append('<a href="javascript:" onClick="delIt(this)"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" style="color:red;"></i> </a>');

function new_link()
    {
        jQuery('#newlink').append('<div class="row">'+repeater.html()+'</div>');
    }
    function delIt(element)
    {
    console.log(jQuery(element).parents('.row'))
        jQuery(element).parents('.row').remove();
    }
    function getMax(element){
       var max = jQuery(element).find(':selected').data("max");
    jQuery(element).parents('.row').find('input[name="nombre[]"]').prop('max',max);
 console.log(max);

}
```

Comment: </div> missing is only in copy and paste

if i do the change i've got this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node':
parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at delIt ((index):366)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick ((index):1)
delIt @ (index):366
onclick @ (index):1

the delIt function work with delIt(this.parentNode.parentNode.id)

thanks

Comment: You use Jquery on max function, why you don't use Jquery for other functions